# Triggered Events in Marionette.ItemView

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

This is a code fragment of my ItemView:

```
class List.GridRow extends Backbone.Marionette.ItemView
  tagName: 'tr'
  triggers:
    'click': 'row:clicked'
```

Then in my Composite view I am doing this:

```
class List.GridView extends Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView
  template: 'mapping/list/templates/grid'
  itemView: List.GridRow
  itemViewContainer: 'tbody'

  initialize: (options) ->
    @listenTo @, 'itemview:row:clicked', (itemView, data) -> @rowClicked(itemView, data)

  rowClicked: (clickedItemView, data) =>

    # I need the original event information to check of the ctrl or shift key was pressed?
    #if !e.ctrlKey && !e.shiftKey
```

What I am trying to do here is to pass the original event information into the trigger handler but I haven't figure it out yet? Is there a way to do this with Marionette? Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The intent of the `triggers` is to provide a minimal event configuration for minimal needs within the view, while also preventing leaky abstractions. Passing the original event args out of the view breaks the abstraction of the view, which is what should be in control of the event args.

If you need the control and shift key information, you'll want to avoid the `triggers` configuration and use standard events that publish the info you need.

```
class List.GridRow extends Backbone.Marionette.ItemView
  tagName: 'tr'
  events:
    'click': 'rowClicked'
  rowClicked (e) ->
    @trigger "row:clicked", 
      control: e.ctrlKey, 
      shift: e.shiftKey
```

Comment: Hi Derick, thanks for your answer. I forgot to mentioned that I was using events at the moment and it is pretty simple too I just was wondering if I was missing something. What you are saying about encapsulation makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @derick-bailey - I know this is non-standard and not recommended, but does your example above circumvent the benefit of Marionette?  i.e do those event bindings create memory leaks?